# Contributions with Stripe returning user to contribution profile from with "Your browser session has expired . . . " Error

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, stripe

We are using CiviCRM 5.54.0 on WordPress 6.0.2

Hello,
I know this problem has been mentioned several times on this forum, but none of the posted solutions are working for me.
I became aware of the problem last wee prior to upgrading to the latest CiviCRM version. I upgraded hoping it would fix it. It only happens when using Stripe to complete the transaction. It does not happen when using PayPal Standard.

After filling out and submitting the contribution profile form with Stripe, the user is then redirected back to that same form with the error highlighted; **"Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form. If you experience continued difficulties, please contact us for assistance."**

The email receipt is delivered and the transaction is completed on the backend, but they are not redirected to the Thank You page like they should be. This gives the user the impression that their payment did not go through and they will try again, thus being double-charged.

[image]

I enabled all the debuggers, including the one provided with the Stripe extension. Literally nothing is showing up in the logs related to this issue. I checked this forum for a solution and I can confirm that a Basepage is configured. We are not using a caching plugin and never were using one. The profile forms are embedded in a Wordpress page as you can see below.
[image]

[image]

![enter image description here

The civicrm.settings.php files does have that clean URL script in in like one person suggested.
[image]

And the permalinks are set to POST NAME.
[image]

I am really lost to what is going on here.  What am I missing? I am being pressured to resolve this as soon as possible because our members are submitting payment multiple times.I hope someone here can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be your civicrm.settings.php is missing permalink_structure check?

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_CLEANURL')) {
  if (function_exists('variable_get') && variable_get('clean_url', '0') != '0') {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  elseif ( function_exists('config_get') && config_get('system.core', 'clean_url') != 0) {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  elseif( function_exists('get_option') && get_option('permalink_structure') != '' ) {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  else {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so  much. That was the answer. I just went and added that third line and it is resolved now.